# form.is_valid() returning false with file attachments

Tags: python, django

I have a form page which asks for file upload, but in the views.py page, form.is_valid() is always returning 'False'. The following is the forms.py:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class Upload_resume(forms.Form):
    f_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=64, required=True)
    s_name = forms.CharField(label='Second Name', max_length=64, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone_no = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'number'}))
    resume = forms.Field(label='Upload Resume', widget = forms.FileInput, required = True )
```

The following is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Upload_resume
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage

def up_resume(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            print(key, value)
        form = Upload_resume(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print form.is_valid()
        print form.errors
        print type(form.errors)
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
(u'resume', u'NBA Meeting.docx')
(u'f_name', u'Jeril')
(u'phone_no', u'9784644334')
(u's_name', u'K')
(u'csrfmiddlewaretoken', u'9z6I0VaNGESR49iBHXvHwCGRRlGcjH1v')
(u'email', u'jeril.work@gmail.com')
False
<ul class="errorlist"><li>resume<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
<class 'django.forms.utils.ErrorDict'>
```

What might be the error? The name of the file that I uploaded is displaying correctly, but still i get an error. Could anyone help. I am new to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `POST` request is missing the file. The `form` tag in your template should have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` when you are trying to upload a file.